# Ler dados, adicioná-los em uma lista e depois imprimi-los

Tags: java

Tenho que criar uma classe `Agenda`, e então criar uma lista de agendas e imprimir.

Meu `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Agenda> lista = new ArrayList<Agenda>();
    Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite o nome");
    agenda.setNome(scanner.next()); 

    System.out.println("Deseja digitar outro ? ");
    String resp = scanner.next();

    while(resp.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        System.out.println("Digite o nome");
        agenda.setNome(scanner.next());
    }

    lista.add(agenda);
    System.out.println(lista);
}
```

Desse jeito, caso o usuário digitasse mais de 2 contatos, iria aparecer apenas o último.

Eu estou tentando pensar em uma solução, mas não consegui imaginar nada para resolver (imprimir todos os contatos digitados).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do `while` você está mudando a mesma instância de `Agenda` (não está criando uma nova, que entendi ser a intenção). Além disso, se `resp` for `"Y"`, ele entrará em *loop* infinito, pois `resp` não é atualizado dentro do `while`, então seu valor continuará sendo `"Y"` e ele nunca sairá deste *loop*.

Se `resp` não for `"Y"`, ele não entra no `while` e você adiciona a agenda na lista (somente uma). Então a primeira coisa é arrumar este loop para sempre ler um novo valor de `resp` (para saber se deve continuar ou não lendo mais dados), e sempre criar uma nova agenda para adicionar na lista (em vez de mudar a mesma).

Então primeiro vamos mudar a classe `Agenda`, adicionando um construtor que recebe o nome:

```
public class Agenda {
    private String nome;

    public Agenda(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }
}
```

Estou assumindo que só faz sentido criar uma agenda se ela tiver um nome. Então não tem porque ter um construtor sem parâmetros, que cria uma agenda sem nome. [Só crie construtores que façam sentido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052). Também retirei o *setter* porque não parece haver uso para ele (a menos que haja alguma regra que determine que uma agenda pode mudar de nome - veja mais sobre *getters* e *setters* [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=getter%20setter%20encapsulamento)).

Agora vamos arrumar nosso *loop*. Um detalhe é que o método [`Scanner::next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) só vai ler a entrada até encontrar um espaço, então se o nome digitado for `"Fulano de Tal"`, o método `next()` só retorna "Fulano" (e a próxima chamada de `next()` leria o "de"). Podemos resolver isso trocando as chamadas de `next()` por [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--), que consome toda a entrada até encontrar uma quebra de linha (no caso, o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> digitado pelo usuário). Então ficaria:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Agenda> lista = new ArrayList<Agenda>();
String resp;
do {
    System.out.println("Digite o nome");
    lista.add(new Agenda(scanner.nextLine()));

    System.out.println("Deseja digitar outro ? ");
    resp = scanner.nextLine();
} while (resp.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")); // enquanto resp for Y, continua no loop
```

Ou seja, eu leio um nome, crio a agenda com esse nome e adiciono-a na lista. Em seguida, pergunto se o usuário quer digitar outro nome, e baseado na resposta, ele continua ou não no `do`/`while`. Se quiser, também pode ser assim:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Digite o nome");
    lista.add(new Agenda(scanner.nextLine()));

    System.out.println("Deseja digitar outro ? ");
    if (! "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine()))
        break;  // se usuário digitou algo diferente de Y, interrompe o while
}
```

No caso, o `break` interrompe o *loop*.

Por fim, basta imprimir a lista, fazendo um `for` por seus elementos e imprimindo um a um:

```
for (Agenda agenda : lista) {
    System.out.println(agenda.getNome());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia fazer um for que percorresse um array ao mesmo tempo que faz a pergunta, ai caso a pergunta for "Y" ele salvaria na posição 0 do array a string digitada, após digitar ele iria refazer a pergunta e ai se caso a resposta for "Y" ele salvaria o valor digitado na posição 1 do array, se a respostas for diferente de "Y" ele encerraria o for dá pergunta e depois iria mostrar o array. Lembrando que na hora de exibir um array precisa-se de um for para percorre-lo. Boa sorte!